# How I can set the correct orientation in the imageView from src

Tags: java, android, imageview

in my project I try to set an image in a ScrollView. I copy the image that is portrait from my pc and paste in Android Studio but when i set the image it appears rotated 90 degrees. How can I set the image as I want?

The image is a photo and the photo is rotated.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="-10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        android:layout_below="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/scrollView"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/imagen"
            android:src="@mipmap/foto"

            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use rotation in XML:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/imagen"
        android:src="@mipmap/foto"
        android:rotation="90"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```